# Why the value of SIP timer T4 is chosen as 5 seconds?

Tags: transactions, sip

In RFC 3261, timer T4 is defined as "Maximum duration a message will remain in the network" and "T4 represents the amount of time the network will take to clear messages between client and server transactions".

How does a SIP message is flushed or how does network clear messages between client and server transactions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are just arbitrary chosen values.
Usually 5 sec is enough for UDP on the globe and also if you have more than 5 sec delays for the packets, then we can’t talk about real time VoIP anymore.
Some network buffer is likely to throw it before this will expire.

A lot of SIP stack is doesn’t implement these timers so strictly (and of course most of sip implementations are not running on real time OS).

Comment: One supplementary question - "The purpose of timer D, K, I, J is to consume the message which comes later. This helps in minimizing unnecessary message to SIP Core". Is this understanding right?

Comment: I don't clearly understand this. From where exactly are you reading this text?

Comment: I mean "the purpose of these timers is to handle re transmission. If these timers were not there, then SIP Core is suppose to re transmit".  So by having these timers all the re transmissions are handled by transaction layer and SIP Core is not burdened for these late re transmission. Is this correct?